# Do i need to encode/decode Laravel's APP_KEY to use in my Android project?

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit2, okhttp

in my Laravel project i have a generated key in my .env that looks like this:

`APP_KEY=base64:randomcharactershere`

And upon researching i found that i need to use it to establish a session.
In my Android project i'm using Retrofit2 and OkHttp3, the following code being the interceptor sent every time a request is made:

```
builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
           @Override
           public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
               Request original = chain.request();
               Request request = original.newBuilder()
                       .header("APP_KEY", "base64:randomcharactershere")
                       .method(original.method(), original.body())
                       .build();

               return chain.proceed(request);
           }
       });
```

problem is, i dont know whether or not should i just put the generated key in the `.header("APP_KEY", "key value")`, or should i decode the given key since it has "base64:" in front of it or what, i just know that before Laravel 5.4 the key would be a String and i would just put it directly there and it would return onResponse method just fine, but now when i do it, it always returns onFailure and i have already checked to see if it is a network connection error and it is. Can someone shine some light about what should i do with that key or why is it not working like before?

Comment: No... don't put your APP_KEY anywhere on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be revealing the `APP_KEY` outside of your application as it would be used in encryption of sensitive data (like cookies and sessions). Instead, you should take a look at [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) (compatible with Laravel 5.3+)

The Passport library will let you create a API Key that you can share with your Android app.